# insert query syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I keep getting an error saying incorrect syntax near where. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
string strSession = objGetSession.GetEmailFromSession();
con.Open();
string strInsertFnLn = "Insert into AUserAddress (FirstName, LastName) values (@FirstName, @LastName) where AUser_ID = (Select ID from AUser where Email ='" + strSession + "')";

using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strInsertFnLn, con))
{
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtEditFirstName.Text);
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtEditLastName.Text);
    //Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEditEmail.Text);
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: use update or remove where clause from query.

Comment: Why YOu Using `WHERE` WITH `Insert` query?

Comment: `INSERT` cannot be scoped by `WHERE`. [See the freely available SQL SErver Books Online documentation on `INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) Also: ***why*** are you using parameters for the `INSERT` (**good!!**), but then again concatenating the rest of the SQL statement as string..... use parameters **everywhere!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.FirstName = @FirstName,
        a.LastName = @LastName
FROM    AUserAddress a
        INNER JOIN AUser b
            ON a.AUser_ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.Email = @Email
```

so the full statement will look like this,

```
string strSession = objGetSession.GetEmailFromSession();            
string connString = "connection string here";
string strInsertFnLn = @"
                            UPDATE  a
                            SET     a.FirstName = @FirstName,
                                    a.LastName = @LastName
                            FROM    AUserAddress a
                                    INNER JOIN AUser b
                                        ON a.AUser_ID = b.ID
                            WHERE   b.Email = @Email
                        ";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strInsertFnLn, con))
    {
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtEditFirstName.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtEditLastName.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", strSession);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // don't hide it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 exactly - use a `@Email` parameter to make this a really nice, safe SQL statement !

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the line

```
string strInsertFnLn = "Insert into AUserAddress (FirstName, LastName) 
   values (@FirstName, @LastName) where 
   AUser_ID = (Select ID from AUser where Email ='" + strSession + "')";
```

What is the use of `where` condition in this query
It should be like

```
string strInsertFnLn = "Insert into AUserAddress (FirstName, LastName) 
                            values (@FirstName, @LastName)";
```

### Edit 1

Or if you want to update the the record then it should be as follow

```
 string strInsertFnLn = "update AUserAddress set FirstName=@FirstName, 
                       LastName=@LastName where 
   AUser_ID = (Select ID from AUser where Email ='" + strSession + "')";
```